# Non-blocking ClientRequest.write() for Node.js

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

According to [http.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L470) the `ClientRequest.write(chunk,encoding)` method of node's `http`module is blocking: The control flow is paused until all data (the current one and all buffered data) is sent.

I want to simultaneously send a larger amount of data using several parallel connections. Is there any (direct) way of creating a non-blocking version of the method just like `ClientRequest.write(chunk,encoding,callback)` where the data is sent "in the background" and a callback handler (or event) is triggered when sending has been completed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code has changed since you sent the link, so it is hard to see where you are pointing at in the code.  That said, my understanding is that it is not blocking at the network level, just to the extent it blocks in JavaScript.  So even with that "blocking" call, you can have several parallel connections, and each can be sending data across the wire concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Node's Stream.pipe() to stream the data into multiple other streams.
e.g:

```js
var w1 = fs.createWriteStream('input-1');
var w2 = fs.createWriteStream('input-2');
request.pipe(w1);
request.pipe(w2);
```